# Update to El Capitan (10.11 15A215h) and Xcode doesn't work

Tags: xcode7, osx-elcapitan, ios8.4

I don't remember what my previous Xcode Version is, maybe 6.3.2 or 6.4. When I upgrade to Developer Preview Mac OS El Capitan Version, I could not use Xcode.

Comment: hi, I modified my question, I find the problem and I solved it, so I want to share it with others.

Comment: probably a better question for https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I download the Xcode 7 beta 3 (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/)

Then I installed it, however, My IPhone is iOS 8.4, And it just says unavailable. I follow the instruction and open Windows->Device, It says

> "couldn't find the developer disk image"

it doesn't contains the IPhoneOS platform. So I want to install Xcode 6.4, cause it contains iOS 8.4 image, But it says

> "Application Xcode can't be used with this OS X version"

I want to combine Xcode 6.4 and Xcode 7 together, So I find a solution: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/7698

if you download Xcode 6.4 posted yesterday,  then copy
     Contents>Developer>Platforms>iPhoneOS.platform>DeviceSupport>8.4 (12H141)
to the Xcode 7 beta, it seems to work fine. Yes, IPhone Connected.

Finally, I combine El Capitan, iOS 8.4, Xcode 7 and worked well.

Comment: Working with El Capitan beta 4 and Xcode 6.4 out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch old xcode versions (6.1, 6.4) on El Capitan:

```
/Applications/Xcode6.4.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode </dev/null &>/dev/null &
```

You can change Xcode6.4 as per your name of xcode file in application.